# Symfony2 nginx automatic logout

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have a project in Symfony 2 (nginx, MySQL).

I looked at nginx access.log file and found something very interesting.

It appears that I get automatic route calling from my application.

This Is my access.log:

10.15.4.104 - - [18/Jun/2016:09:32:52 +0200] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302

10.15.4.104 - - [18/Jun/2016:09:32:52 +0200] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200

It seems that in the same second, two routes get called (logout and then in the same second /login).

I am using FOSUserBundle.

This is my part of my config.yml

```
translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
#serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
    gc_probability: 0
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true
```

Comment: usually /logout redirects to /login, which shows in the logs 302 -> 200, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: SO is not a blog. Where is the question? What do you want to understand? What do you want to achieve? Where is your problem?

Comment: yes. you're right. But first "/logout" was not called from my application nor from logged in user. That is my main problem. How did that happen? It's like application by itself called the /logout route....